# How to configure jasper reports in java code

Tags: java, jasper-reports, filenotfoundexception

I had created a java application which creates a jasper report whenever user clicks the print button it provides a report. 
code:
String

```
srcfile1="C:\\Users\\VINO\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\rework\\src\\rework\\report1.jasper";
JasperPrint firstsecondlinked = JasperFillManager.fillReport(srcfile1,map,cons);
```

I copied the same to the colleague but it doesn't works fine giving an error states that file not found.
 As to create a application how to name the source file in the string?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following.

- Specify the paths in some properties file and read it by loading that file. While deploying your application to some other machine, change the path before deployment.

application-resources.properties
report1.path=''

- If it's a web-application, you can access any resource inside your application by using request.getContextPath(). You will not need to hard code it like C:\Users\VINO.. Only the relative path will suffice.